# Items in slider window not showing until inspect element is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

The items in the "Accessories" pane are not displayed upon loading in the `PrestaShop` web site we developed. The height of the element (pane) shows `0px`.

However, once the "Inspect element" function in Firefox or "inspect" in Google Chrome is used, all items appear in the Accessories window correctly.

Yet they disappear again if the page is reloaded or refreshed!
Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Below are the links to sample pages:

http://www.filterdepot.ca/index.php?id_product=8&controller=product

http://www.filterdepot.ca/index.php?id_product=78&controller=product

Comment: Maybe you should call a `resize` event?

Comment: Obviously it's `resize` event, but I'm too lazy to read your code and find where it is.

Comment: opening the inspector probably triggers a resize...

Comment: the `bx-viewport` Class is gotting 0px height before resize 
I think you should look behind the js Function (of the slider) that resize the box content

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you all for a very quick response and for your suggestions on where to look it up to solve the problem. In a meantime, I would greatly appreciate any further suggestions or reference links.

Comment: The items displayed in the "Accessories" Tab pane in Jquery BxSlider in the started to appear  after I changed the "easing" function from "null" to "linear" (or "ease") in the jquery.bxslider.js

Comment: One problem solved, another emerged. The items are displayed in the "Accessories" Tab pane as slides of Jquery BxSlider. They appear correctly after I changed the "easing" function in jquery.bxslider.js from "null" to "linear" (or "ease"). Here is the link: http://bxslider.com/options However, this prompted another BxSlider on the same page to show all products in the same category at the same time, not as slides. Playing with different settings for jquery.bxslider.js so far didn't bring a desired result. I'd highly appreciate any further suggestions or help. Thx. Alex